# Error with active reports / System.Drawing.Image in apppool 4.0 while client is 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, activereports

### Setup

#### Service

Using `IIS 7.5` with application pool set to `v4.0 integrated`, code is compiled with `.NET Framework v3.5`

#### Client

Using `WinForms` client compiled with `.NET Framework v3.5`

### Dataflow

1. Service loads or creates (`new System.Drawing.Bitmap()`) a `System.Drawing.Image` object and stores it into a `DataDynamics.ActiveReports.ActiveReport.Watermark`
2. The `DataDynamics.ActiveReports.ActiveReport` is then being compressed and sent to the client application
3. Client uses `DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Viewer.Viewer` to load that object and displays it.

### Symptoms

In the initial setup, the client will get the exception that it can not find the assembly `System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`.

Personally I would expected that if the service application and the client application are both compiled with the `.NET Framework v3.5` that they would use `System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0`..

If the application pool is running in `v2.0`, the dataflow works correctly.

If the application pool is running in `v4.0`, the service and the client are compiled with `CLR4` the dataflow works correctly.

### Question

To sum things up:

1. AppPool `v4.0`, Client `v3.5`, Service `v3.5` = Error
2. AppPool `v2.0`, Client `v3.5`, Service `v3.5` = No error
3. AppPool `v4.0`, Client `v4.x`, Service `v4.x` = No error

Since option 2 and 3 are not an option right now, I humbly ask if anybody has an idea how to solve option 1.

### Things I tried so far

1. Putting the explicit assembly version into the `compilation` section in the `Web.config`

   ```
   <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true">
       <!--<assemblies>
           <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
       </assemblies>-->
   </compilation>
   ```
2. Adding an explicit framework version attribute to the `compilation` element `targetframework="3.5"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the root cause of the problem at hand is located deep in the implementation of active reports itself. If a [`DataDynamics.ActiveReports.ActiveReport.Document`](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/ActiveReports.Document~DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Document.Document.html) object is being saved into a stream by a call to the [`Save(Stream)`](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/ActiveReports.Document~DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Document.Document_members.html) method the current objects `ResourceManager` content will be written to the stream in binary format. The `ResourceManager` is containing assembly references that will be written to the stream as assembly strings.

So when the stream will be opened on the client side the `Load(Stream)` method will try to restore those assembly references resulting in the described error.

The following *hack* is what I've come up with to solve that issue.

```
static byte[] ReplaceAssemblyRef(MemoryStream stream)
{
    byte[] buffer = stream.GetBuffer();
    byte[] search = new byte["System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".Length * sizeof( char )];
    byte[] replace = new byte["System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".Length * sizeof( char )];
    Buffer.BlockCopy( "System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".ToCharArray(), 0, search, 0, search.Length );
    Buffer.BlockCopy( "System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".ToCharArray(), 0, replace, 0, replace.Length );

    IEnumerable<int> indicies = Enumerable.Range( 0, buffer.Length - search.Length + 1 );

    for( int i = 0; i < search.Length; i++ )
        indicies = indicies.Where( n => buffer[n + i] == search[i] ).ToArray();

    foreach( int i in indicies )
        Buffer.BlockCopy( replace, 0, buffer, i, replace.Length );

    return buffer;
}
```

Please be advised that the better solution is to align your service and client framework versions than to mess with binary memory streams.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange issue.  My guess is that it has to do with serialization of the image.   Just for testing, can you save the image to a file as a PNG or JPG then have AR load it from the file.